# Why the pointer fails to take new value back? iOS

Tags: ios, function, pointers, uibutton

Question are as follows:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIButton *startBtn;

-(void)createView
{
  int btnW = 22;
  int btnH = 14;


  self.startBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"%@",self.startBtn);//log1

  [self createButton:@selector(startBtnDidClicked:) frame:CGRectMake( screenW - btnW , screenH/2 - btnH, btnW, btnH) addedto:self.view andEqualToBtn:self.startBtn];

  //quetion is here
  NSLog(@"%@",self.startBtn);//log5 --same as log1 (the expected value should be different from log1)
 }

- (void)createButton:(SEL)action  frame:(CGRect)frame addedto:(UIView *)parentView andEqualToBtn:(UIButton *)button
{

  UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

  NSLog(@"%@",btn);  //log2
  button = btn;
  NSLog(@"%@",button); // log3  --same as log2

  NSLog(@"%@",self.startBtn); //log4  -- same as log1
  [button addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [parentView addSubview:button];
}
```

I wanna to take the value back, **so the expected result should be : log5 should be diffrent from log1,and same as log2. I wander that why log3 could do this, but the pointer fail to take the new value out?**

Thx a lot for your help!

Comment: Because they are two different buttons, and `self.startBtn` only points to one of them.

Comment: thx a lot!!  i should learn more about this!  thx for your help  ~O(∩_∩)O~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `andEqualToBtn:(UIButton *)button`, you're getting the value of a pointer, not a reference to the actual pointer.

If you need to change what the pointer points to, you need `andEqualToBtn:(UIButton **)button` and then fix your argument and assignment to match.

Comment: This could work!  thx a lot!!   I should learn more about this.  thx bro.

Answer (score 1):

As written, there is no reason to expect "log1" and "log5" to be different. `btn` and `button` are two separate `UIButton` instances. `button` is equal to `self.startBtn`.

I suggest you reorganize your code to something like this:

```
-(void)createView
{
    int btnW = 22;
    int btnH = 14;

    self.startBtn = [self createButton:@selector(startBtnDidClicked:) frame:CGRectMake( screenW - btnW , screenH/2 - btnH, btnW, btnH) addedto:self.view];
 }

- (UIButton *)createButton:(SEL)action frame:(CGRect)frame addedto:(UIView *)parentView
{
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [btn addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [parentView addSubview:btn];

    return btn;
}
```

Comment: I 've just confused the concept of  pointer and of pointer to pointer, thx bro!